# How to make material UI dialog Re-sizable and dragabel

Tags: popupwindow, material-ui

Want to make my Material UI dialog re-sizable and draagabel like following link

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/p7o2mkg4/][1]
```

any help?

Answer (score 1):

For draggable you can use `react-draggable`. Have created a codesandbox for your reference. https://codesandbox.io/s/lp8q9r92x9

Comment: This codesandbox does not make use of `react-draggable`. The resizing module works beautifully though!

Answer (score 0):

In that fiddle the author have used jQuery UI to add Resizable and Draggable to the modal.

Here's a link for that: https://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.12.1&components=101100000100101000000000010000000000000000000000

Answer (score 0):

The mui Dialog component's page has this - https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/#draggable-dialog